# "Connection error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Tags: php

I develop a website locally in my laptop in php. In local machine is running fine but when i make it live there it is giving me error that is

> Connection error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)".

I am using correct information for database connectivity I don't know why it is happening.

Comment: Can Anyone Help me to solve this error

Comment: I know this question is repeated many times but i am unable to solve it and now this error has got on my nerves

Comment: Does your live site really use the root sql user with no password?

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a problem with your database credentials.The database is complaining that you did not pass the **password** for **root** user.
Most likely user **root** of your local database server doesn't have a password.

Comment: Hi @WaqarChohan. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answer-er and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.